# Jquery ui-dialog title buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

jquery ui dialog show a title bar with an icon (X) to close it.

I have to append one more icon.

This new icon is using to show a help dialog.

This is an example with minimize icon:
http://www.droptoframe.com/demos/minimizedemo.html

Its possible to do that? How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following when initiliazing the dialog:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    title: '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the curiosity, the page you sent itself shows how to do this. It's using a custom extension for Dialog available at http://www.droptoframe.com/jquery.dialog.minimize.js

Everything you need to know how to do this is there.

Answer (score 0):

**Might be some buddy want to add title attribute in dialog box button.**

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonset button > span').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
});
```

**Try this.**